# Wann soll man "um" oder "über" nutzen, um "about" zu übersetzen?

Tags: english-to-german, preposition

Präpositionen sind mir der schwierigste Teil der deutsche Sprache. Sie übersetzen nicht genau aus Englisch. Jede Präposition hat verschiedene Bedeutungen. Wann ich auf Englisch "about" benutze, soll ich denn auf Deutsch "über" oder "um" wählen?

Beispiele:

> The man is talking **about** flowers. / Der Mann spricht **über** Blumen.
>
> The man is worried **about** his child. / Der Mann sorgt sich **um** sein Kind.

Wie soll man zwischen die beide entscheiden?

Welchen Fall nimmt "über", wenn es so benutzt wird, Akkusativ oder Dativ?

Comment: Wahrscheinlich gibt es einige Faustregeln, die ich nicht kenne. Am Ende wirst Du aber die Präposition zusammen mit dem Verb lernen müssen, z. B. „sich um etwas sorgen“. (Da siehst Du auch noch einen Fehler in Deinem Beispiel...)

Comment: Hi, darf ich ein paar Kleinigkeiten zu deiner Frage anmerken? „Übersetzen“ können auf deutsch nur Personen, d.h. man kann z.B. nicht sagen „Sie [die Präpositionen] übersetzen aus Englisch“. Wenn man so etwas sagen will, muss man es als Passiv ausdrücken: „Man kann sie nicht genau aus dem Englischen übersetzen“ oder „Sie lassen sich nicht genau aus dem Englischen übersetzen“.

Comment: Außerdem ist „wann“ nicht die richtige Übersetzung für „when“, wenn es als Konjunktion verwendet wird. „Wann“ wird nur verwendet, wenn du nach einem Zeitpunkt fragst (z.B. „Wann kommt die Bahn?“). In allen anderen Fällen heißt es „wenn“. Den Fehler machen englische Muttersprachler oft ;)

Answer (score 2):

Gibt es überhaupt eine Sprache, deren Präpositionen in andere Sprache eindeutig übersetzt werden können? Bei Präpositionen kann man nicht einmal hoffen, eine 1:1-Übersetzung zu finden. Die sind äußerst nicht-lokal, im Sinne, dass man mehr als ein Stückchen eines Satzes bräuchte, um die richtige Übersetzung einer Präposition wählen zu können. D. h., man übersetzt nur selten eine Präposition. In der Regel lernt man sog. *Verben mit Präpositional-Ergänzung* (nach dieser Angabe kannst du deine Lieblingstabelle googlen). Die muss man halt lernen, denn die Liste möglicher Übersetzungen ohne Hilfe eines Verbes wäre viel zu lang und so hilfreich fürs Lernen wie anzufangen, das Wörterbuch zu lesen.

Ein zweiter Grund: *About* entsprechen nicht nur *um* und *über*, sondern auch *herum*, *für*, *gegen* und vielleicht noch mehr.

Die zur zweiten Frage entsprechende Antwort ist: *Akkusativ.*

Comment: Ich suche keine 1-1 Übersetzung. Ich will verstehen, wie sie auf Deutsch benutzt werden. Auf welche Fälle nutzt man ein oder die andere? Als englischer Muttersprachler ist es schwer zu unterscheiden, und das ist, warum ich gefragt habe.

Comment: Denn soll eine gute Antwort diese Wörter auch enthalten.

Answer (score 2):

2) Akk. oder Dat. (Position)

> Edit:
>   Welchen Fall nimmt "über", wenn es so benutzt wird, Akkusativ oder Dativ?
>   `Der Mann spricht über [wen oder was?] Blumen.`
>   **Akkusativ** in diesem Fall

1) I think it is a better strategy to not to emanate (?!) from the english preposition but rather from the sentence itself and the usage of the particular german prepositions. If you do so, you will cease thinking a english version first and then trying to find the german counterpart, but instead go the direct way moving with the german environs of your head.

Of course this is a bit idealistic. However, this seems to work better. Therefore - in the given case and besides the fixed connection of some verbs with prepositions - I recommend to check the different use cases of `um` and `über`.

Here is an overview, essentially taken from [here](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/praepositionen/die-bedeutung-der-prapositionen-ubersicht/die-bedeutung-der-prapositionen-um/) and [here](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/praepositionen/die-bedeutung-der-prapositionen-ubersicht/die-bedeutung-der-prapositionen-uber/)

## Präposition `um`

- lokal: Position
  `Um das Haus stehen viele Bäume.`
- lokal: Richtung
  `Der Mann geht um die Ecke.`
- temporal: unbestimmter Zeitpunkt
  Die Präposition `um` beschreibt einen unbestimmten Zeitpunkt. Die Unbestimmtheit des Zeitpunktes wird oft zusätzlich durch die Adverbien *ungefähr*, *circa*, o.ä. betont.
  In diesen Bedeutungen wird `um` oft durch *herum* zusätzlich betont.
  `Um 1900 wanderte sein Großvater nach Amerika aus.`
  euivalent zu:
  `Ungefähr um 1900 wanderte sein Großvater nach Amerika aus.`
  `Um 1900 herum wanderte sein Großvater nach Amerika aus.`
- temporal: bestimmter Zeitpunkt (Uhrzeit)
  `Der Unterricht beginnt um 9 Uhr.`
  Unterscheide:
  `Um 14.00 Uhr herum = ca. 14.00 Uhr`
  `Um 14.00 Uhr = genau 14.00 Uhr`
- präpositionale Verbergänzung
  z. B.: `bitten`, `bewerben`, `sorgen`. `ringen`, etc

## Präposition `über`

- lokal: Position (+ Dat.)
  `Die Lampe hängt über dem Tisch.`

lokal: Richtung (+ Akk.)
`Ich hänge die Lampe über den Tisch.`
`Wir fahren über die Türkei in den Iran.`

- temporal: begrenzte Zeitdauer (Datum) (+ Akk.)
  `Die letzten zwei Monate über war ich im Ausland.`
  `Über die letzten zwei Monate war ich im Ausland.`
  equivalent zu:
  `Während der letzten zwei Monate war ich im Ausland.`
- adverbial
  `Die Fahrt nach Berlin dauert über sechs Stunden.`
  equivalent zu:
  `Die Fahrt nach Berlin dauert mehr als sechs Stunden.`
- präpositionale Verbergänzung
  z. B.: `beschweren`, `sprechen`, `lachen`. `berichten`, `verhandeln`, etc

Comment: Meinst du, der Fall der Präposition hängt davon ab, worüber man spricht? *sprechen über* ist immer *Akk.*, ne?

Comment: Please be more specific, @c.p.. What are you refering to?

Comment: To your *2)* (first line). It's exclusively accusative. I mean, if you want to answer the question as is posed above.

Comment: Reading the question carefully, I think it's accusative "`wenn es so benutzt wird`".

Comment: @c.p. Nein, der Fall der Präposition hängt davon ab, welche Funktion die Präposition jeweils hat: Einleitung von Adverbialen (welche Sorte Adverbial) oder Einleitung von Präpositionalobjekten (zu welchem Verb?)

Comment: @Toscho Eben, das einzige hier zu diskutierende Verb ist *sprechen*. Darum geht es die Frage. Wenn ich die richtig verstehe. Ich meine, wie ich die Antwort verstehe "sprechen über" könnte auch *sprechen über+Dativ* sein. Das ist was ich hier nicht nachvollziehen kann. Weil es kann nicht davon abhängen, ob man "wir sprechen über das Wetter" oder "Wir sprechen über *der Schweiz*". Oder vielleicht ist es richtig "wir sprechen über einem Tisch", was meinte, vielleicht, dass wir über dem Tisch schweben :D

Comment: @Toscho The question seems to be about `über` in connection with `sprechen` (if  `wenn es so benutzt wird` refers to the given example). So @c.p.'s statement probably is correct

Comment: @embert: Ah, I was referring to c.p.'s first comment overlooking his second comment.

Comment: @c.p. Ja. In `sprechen über […]` kann das `über` verschiedene Funktionen einleiten. `über das Wetter sprechen`: Präpositionalobjekt von `sprechen` (Akkusativ). `über dem Tisch sprechen`: Lokaladverbial (Zustandsangabe, Dativ). `über die Köpfe der Zuschauer hinweg sprechen`: Lokaladverbial (Richtungsangabe, Akkusativ).

Answer (score 2):

Mit einfachen Regeln ist im Bereich Präpositionen nicht viel zu machen. Präpositionen sind in jeder Sprache ein schwieriger Bereich, vor allem wenn man von einer Sprache zu einer anderen geht. Oft sind Präpositionen fest mit anderen Wörtern
(Verben, Substantiven, Adjektiven gekoppelt), z.B. sprechen über + Thema. Manchmal geht aber auch eine zweite Präposition wie sprechen von + Person/Sache.  Jede einzelne Präposition muß man in einem größeren Lexikon studieren, um einen generellen Überblick über die Verwendungen zu bekommen. Dazu kommen dann noch die vielen speziellen festen Verbindungen zwischen speziellen Wortarten und Präpositionen.

Man könnte sagen, dass es zum Gebrauch der Präpositionen ein eigenes Hilfsmittel geben müßte, weil Grammatik und Lexikon diesen Bereich nicht genügend abdecken können. Aber so etwas wie eine Präpositionslehre habe ich noch nicht gesehen.

So gibt es nur eines. Jeder muß sich selbst intensiv mit Präpositionen beschäftigen.

Answer (score 1):

Speziell zu dem "sorgen um": Es gibt auch "besorgt sein über". Diese beiden Formulierungen haben eine leicht unterschiedliche Bedeutung: "sorgen um" ist eine aktive Handlung zum Wohl einer Sache, besorgt sein über bedeutet nur, dass man etwas Besorgnis erregendes zur Kenntnis nimmt.
Sorgen um währe vielleicht etwas besser mit "care about" oder "care for" übersetzt.